# Publishing MVC Solution to Azure VM using Web Deploy results in ERROR_DESTINATION_NOT_REACHABLE

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, multi-tenant, webdeploy, saas

I am trying to publish an MVC solution from Visual Studio 2017 to an Azure VM, I have Enabled IIS and Management Service, Allowed Management Service Port 8172 Inbound Rule in Azure and in the VM Firewall Settings, but i am still getting `ERROR_DESTINATION_NOT_REACHABLE`. I followed the link in the Error Description [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/publish/troubleshooting-web-deploy/web-deploy-error-codes#ERROR_DESTINATION_NOT_REACHABLE) and i have the necessary services started. But i still get this error.

[image]

I tried pinging the server and i get timeout however i successfully establish an RDC. What is the problem here?

Comment: Have you installed msdeploy to the target VM Server

Comment: I have @Saravanan

Comment: The thing i have realised is i cannot even ping the VM i have even completely turned my firewall off yet still same, but i see an inbound rule in Azure that says Block All i cant modify that rule or delete it too.@Saravanan

Comment: I think you may need to have Administrator account in VM. I am not sure, may be someone from DevOps can help you out.